# How to retrieve the variables from 2 on_messages from 2 different users? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am rather new to coding in discord python

Right now I am trying to get the data from 2 on_messages
One is from a discord user who is writing ;stat
One is from a discord bot (not my own) who is giving responding to that

Both of those information I want stored and pushed onto a database.

The code I have right now is:

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(';stats') and message.channel.id == 970590429861003284: #Response from user
        userid = message.author.id
        userfetch = await bot.fetch_user(userid)
        await database.newuser(message, userid, userfetch)
    if message.author.id == [...] and message.channel.id == 970590429861003284: #Response from bot
        newEmbed = database.embedder(message)
        author = newEmbed['author']
        username = author['name'].split("\'s Stats")[0]
```

However, I do not know where to go from here.. since I do not know how to link those 2 different things together

so I want to combine the variables:
userid
username

I have looked into:

- Asyncio (however I do not exactly know how this works, but seemed like gather could do something)
- Documentation in discord.py for on_message and wait_for

Those 2 values are put together from 2 different messages :

- First if catches the first message
- Second IF catches the second message

Those two values I want to put together into a MySQL database (I already have the code for this in another class)

Asyncio & wait_for are two things I found on Google what you could use
On_message is when a message is sent in a server.

My code works fine, but I cannot link those two together.
Cause it's a chain of events (Message A (user1) + Message B(user2)) = Message I want

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](/tour) What do you mean by "link those 2 different things together"? And what is `database`? What do `asyncio`, `on_message` and `wait_for` have to do with your problem? And what's the problem with your code? Does everything work fine? If not, please specify what is wrong with the code and why it doesn't work as expected, and please post errors if any. Do you know JSON and dictionaries?

Comment: Those 2 values are put together from 2 different messages :
- First if catches the first message
- Second IF catches the second message

Those two values I want to put together into a MySQL database (I already have the code for this in another class)

Asyncio & wait_for are two things I found on Google what you could use
On_message is when a message is sent in a server.

My code works fine, but I cannot link those two together. 
Cause it's a chain of events (Message A (user1) + Message B(user2) = Message I want

Comment: Yes I have experience with dictionaries, not so much with JSON

Comment: I guess it would be case-specific. Can you include an example of the type of message you're listening for and the reply the bot sends? You can then try to check for similarities. But this would work only in channels/servers in which messages are not very frequently sent (the bot may respond to the user's message quickly, but two different users shouldn't use the same command together). Is the channel/server too active?

Comment: It would also depend on how much control you/your bot has in the server. If you have enough control or are the server's owner, you can probably ask the users to use another command which you can then somehow redirect and update your database, or if you don't want to invoke the bot's command (as it would be slow and expensive), you can try some other method. Try to think of some other methods or a way to integrate both. It also depends on the bot (whose messages you're listening for)'s code. Nothing is striking my head, but I don't think you can do it easily.

Comment: I had tried making an automator for Dank Memer, but it didn't work as expected (I thought it would work with a simple for loop of `<channel>.send(meme)`s), as apparently, Dank Memer responds only to users and not bots. If the bot has APIs, etc., you can probably use them.

Comment: Does the bot respond to users by referencing the command message? If yes, you only need to look at bot messages